# Using google map in sencha touch

Tags: dictionary, sencha-touch-2

Hi I am facing problem with Google map in sencha touch 2. Following is the code ..

```
                    new Ext.application({
                    name:'Touch Start',
                launch:function(){
            var map = new Ext.Panel({
         fulscreen:true,
         items:[
         {
        xtype:'map',
        useCurrentLocation:true,

        }
 ]

         });
    this.viewport = map;
     }
  });
```

Please Help is anyone know about this

Comment: There's an example of exactly that in the SDk download, why can't you use that?

Comment: Well i am new to sencha so dnt knw what are you saying :(

Comment: Download Sencha Touch. Look in the examples folder under maps. There's a fully working example.

Comment: Well i have got it thanx for reply :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all, and before your question gets closed, you're not exactly telling us what the problem is with your code. So, I guess you can be facing two different problems

**Google Maps API is required**

Be sure to add the script tag that load the Google Maps API. [You can find infos here](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/tutorial)

**No Layout**

Your main panel doesn't contain any layout, so it doesn't know how to display its items

Try to add this to the config :

```
layout: 'fit'
```

Here's a working example where the Google Maps API is loaded asynchronously :

http://www.senchafiddle.com/#MhAME

Hope this helped

Comment: Now just tell me can we add this map in One of the tab in penel ??

Comment: You can add it whenever you want